# Create two ForeignKey to one class

Tags: python, django, orm, foreign-keys

I have this problem in this class of the model.

```
class Transferencia(models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    importe = models.FloatField()
    tipo = models.ManyToManyField(Tipo)
    cuentaOrigen = models.OneToOneField(Cuenta)
    cuentaDestino = models.OneToOneField(Cuenta)
    monedaReferencia = models.ForeignKey(Moneda)
    fechaApunte = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    factura = models.ForeignKey(Factura)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Importe: " + self.importe
```

And I've this error

```
ERRORS: walletGestor.Transferencia.cuentaDestino: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Transferencia.cuentaDestino' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Transferencia.cuentaOrigen'.  HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Transferencia.cuentaDestino' or 'Transferencia.cuentaOrigen'. walletGestor.Transferencia.cuentaDestino: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Transferencia.cuentaDestino' clashes with reverse query name for 'Transferencia.cuentaOrigen'.     HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Transferencia.cuentaDestino' or 'Transferencia.cuentaOrigen'. walletGestor.Transferencia.cuentaOrigen: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Transferencia.cuentaOrigen' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Transferencia.cuentaDestino'.  HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Transferencia.cuentaOrigen' or 'Transferencia.cuentaDestino'. walletGestor.Transferencia.cuentaOrigen: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Transferencia.cuentaOrigen' clashes with reverse query name for 'Transferencia.cuentaDestino'.  HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Transferencia.cuentaOrigen' or 'Transferencia.cuentaDestino'.

System check identified 4 issues (0 silenced).
```

Help me please, I need determinate the origin account and the destiny account.

This is the class account

```
class Cuenta(models.Model):
    nombreCuenta = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tipoCuenta = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    importeInicial = models.FloatField()
    excluirEstadisticas = models.BooleanField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombreCuenta +": " + self.importeInicial
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very clearly, you need to add a [`related_name` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

```
cuentaOrigen = models.OneToOneField(Cuenta, related_name="cuentaOrigen")
cuentaDestino = models.OneToOneField(Cuenta, related_name="cuentaDestino")
```